# TypeError - Issue appending items to list

Tags: python

I am reading data from an input file containing MLB player stats. Each line of the file contains 9 elements relating to each player.  I'm trying to calculate a few statistics and add them to the end of the list created with the player stats but am getting a type error specifying `float object is not iterable`.  Here is the code I'm using to populate the list from the input file:

```
def readInput(fileName):
    stats = []
    try:
        fh = open(fileName, "r")
        #populated the stats list
        for line in fh:
            line = line.strip('\n')
            allPlayers = line.split(";")
            stats.append(allPlayers)
        print("Player data has been loaded\n")
        fh.close()
    except:
        print("File not found")
```

In the same function, I've included the following code to calculate the desired statistics and add them to the `stats` list:

```
for k in stats:
    atBats = k[3]
    hits = k[5]
    doubles = k[6]
    triples = k[7]
    homeruns = k[8]
    singles = int(hits) - (int(doubles) + int(triples) + int(homeruns))
    totalBases = int(singles) + (2 * int(doubles)) + (3 * int(triples)) + (4 * int(homeruns))
    battingAvg = int(hits) / int(atBats)
    sluggingPct = int(totalBases) / int(atBats)
    print(battingAvg)
    print(sluggingPct)
    stats.append(battingAvg)
    stats.append(sluggingPct)
return stats
```

Then I receive this message: `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.

Any advice or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you upload the complete stacktrace?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  Python 3.x will give you a float for battingAvg, whereas Python 2.x will give you an integer, probably 0 because hits are generally below at bats.  You will have to have at least one of your arguments to / be a float in Python 2.x to get a floating point batting average.

Comment: Are you trying to add the batting average and slugging percent to the stats for the player, or are you trying to have a list of player stats, followed by the first player's batting average, then slugging percent, then the second player's batting average, then their slugging percent, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you break reading the file into one function, and calculating the stats into another function.  That way you can test the functions separately, and you can reuse them separately.

It looks like you are trying to add battingAvg and sluggingAvg stats to the numbers you already have for each player.

More idiomatic Python would also be to use list comprehensions and context managers.

```
def readInput(fileName):
    try:
        with open(fileName, "r") as fh:
            list_of_players = [line.strip('\n').split(';') for line in fh]
        print("Player data has been loaded\n")
        return list_of_players
    except IOError:
        print("File not found")

def calculate_player_stats(player):    
    atBats = float(player[3])
    hits = int(player[5])
    doubles = int(player[6])
    triples = int(player[7])
    homeruns = int(player[8])
    multibase_hits = sum((doubles, triples, homeruns))
    singles = hits - multibase_hits
    totalBases = singles + (2 * doubles) + (3 * triples) + (4 * homeruns)
    # or total_bases = hits + doubles + homeruns + 2 * (triples + homeruns)
    battingAvg = hits / atBats
    sluggingPct = totalBases / atBats
    print(battingAvg)
    print(sluggingPct)
    player.append(battingAvg)
    player.append(sluggingPct)


def calculateStats(list_of_players):
    for player in list_of_players:
        calculate_player_stats(player)

list_of_players = readInput(fileName)
if list_of_players:
    calculateStats(list_of_players)
return list_of_players
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not the cause of your original issue, you are appending the stats while iterating over them. And you are appending them with `battingAvg` which is definitely not iterable.

```
for k in stats:
    atBats = k[3]  # at one point k is battingAvg, can't index that
    ...
    battingAvg = int(hits) / int(atBats)
    ...
    stats.append(battingAvg)
    ...
return stats
```

#### Update:

By the stack trace you sent in the comments:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "final.py", line 207, in
>    main() File "final.py", line 169, in main stats =
>   readInput(fileName) File "final.py", line 55, in readInput
>   stats.extend(battingAvg) TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

it seems that the code you posted in your question doesn't contain the relevant part. Basically, you are using `extend()` for a non-iterable element (float) - use `append()` to add it to the list.

This is because `extend` takes all the elements from one list, and appends it to a second list. And since there are no elements in `float`, you get the not iterable exception.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Do you have suggestions on a better way to add the results of these calculations to the `stats` list?

Comment: Yes, add them to a different list, and append them to the original outside of the loop. Also, can you paste the whole stack trace with your original error?

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance but I'm not sure where to find the stack trace.

Comment: The stack trace is what's printed on the screen when there's an uncaught exception. Looks like this, though usually longer: `raceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: @pcurry thanks for the advice.  Here is the stack trace:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final.py", line 207, in <module>
    main()
  File "final.py", line 169, in main
    stats = readInput(fileName)
  File "final.py", line 55, in readInput
    stats.extend(battingAvg)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`